# Modal window with an image on Drupal page load?

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, lightbox, drupal-theming

I've just started with Drupal about a month ago, and I only know the basics of Javascript. I'd like to know an easy way for me to display a modal window with an image on my Drupal 7 site, when it loads. I've already tried doing it with the Lightbox2 module and the Colorbox module but I haven't got any success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by writing a custom jquery plugin in your tpl file. For Plugin you can search model box in jquery on internet and paste the code in your tpl file.